# Why does Grails Spring Security channel security replace my controller names with 'grails'?

Tags: grails, https, spring-security, grails-plugin

Note I am using Grails 2.0.4 and spring security core plugin 1.2.7.2

This appears to be a bug but I want to make sure I'm doing things correctly first.  Basically, I want certain URLs secured with HTTPS, and the rest not, seems very standard.  If a user goes to a non-secure URL, I don't want them staying on HTTPS.  Everything works fine until I add this line to accomplish the last point:

```
    '/**':          'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL'
```

at which point for some reason all my secure controller names get rewritten with 'grails' and things break horribly.  So for example if I go to

```
http://localhost:8080/login/index
```

it becomes

```
http://localhost:8080/grails/auth/index.dispatch
```

('grails' is not the name of my app nor do I have any controller named 'grails' - my app runs at root)

If I remove that entry for root wildcard, everything works fine, I no longer get that weird 'grails' in my URL, although I stay on https outside the pages I want secured.

Here is my full configuration.  Note that secure pages don't try and load any insecure resources that I can see, only things defined under 'ANY_CHANNEL'

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/login/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
        '/register/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
        '/changePassword/**':         'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
        '/userAccountManagement/**':    'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',


        '/simpleCaptcha/**': 'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/img/**':        'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/images/**':        'ANY_CHANNEL',
        '/static/**':        'ANY_CHANNEL',

        '/**':          'REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL'  //remove this, everything OK

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/grails/controller/action.dispatch` URIs are what comes out of the Grails URL mapping mechanism.  URL mappings in Grails are implemented by a servlet filter that forwards the request (in the RequestDispatcher sense) to a `/grails` URI, and it's these that drive the DispatcherServlet.

I suspect what's happening here is that the `/**` is causing the channel security filter to fire on these forwarded request URIs as well as the original pre-mapping ones.  Does it work if you put an explicit ANY_CHANNEL for `/grails/**` ahead of the `/**` rule?

Comment: It looks like you were right on - they fixed a bug to stop processing the spring security filter chain on forwards in 1.2.7.3 - and this fixed my problem.  I did not need to implement your suggestion because of this fix. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-175